# What makes EAP-SRP-256 better than SRP?

Tags: passwords, authentication

What is the advantage of the EAP-SRP protocol? Is it only used in wireless?

Comment: Your single sentence questions is comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 3):

[EAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol) is a generic framework for authentication methods; it is mostly a way to encode arbitrary messages which incarnate an authentication algorithm. A protocol which uses EAP is automatically "compatible" with any authentication algorithm which fits in the EAP formalism, among which [EAP-SRP-256](http://rap.dsi.unifi.it/eap-srp-256/) is just one possible method, which builds on SRP.

So EAP-SRP is not "better" than SRP; EAP-SRP *is* SRP, with EAP-styled clothes.